# CGIAR SRTM to xyz using GRASS GIS, with sampling

Tags: grass-gis, srtm

I have used CGIAR interface to select the tiles, like so:
[image]

This resulted in a bunch of `*.zip`-files, and I have extracted them all into
a directory.
Next, I followed the instructions as https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/HOWTO_import_SRTM_elevation_data to turn everything into mosaic,
like so:

```
 #create mosaik (optionally reproject on the fly with -t_srs)
 gdalwarp *.tif srtm_mosaik.tif
 # import
 r.in.gdal input=srtm_mosaik output=srtm_mosaik location=srtm_mosaic_cgiar
```

Finally, I "connect" to the location `srtm_mosaic_cgiar` using `grass-gui` and export the tiles as `xyz` elevation data, using `r.out.xyz` (I use the `File->Export...` drop-down menu).
Now my question is, since this operation appears to be hard on my laptop,
and I can imagine the elevation data of Europe (as I have selected)
is going to be huge, how to "restrict" `r.out.xyz` to sample (somehow) the
exported data, or how to ascertain beforehand the size of the output?

My final goal is rather simple. I would like to have a file with `x,y,z`, where `x,y` refer to a "locus" somehwere in Europe, all the `x,y`s are mutually sufficiently apart (say, `300-500km`), and `z` means the "elevation"
of the respective point `x,y`. If there is a misconception on my part at this
stage already, please feel free to correct me. I am new to GIS.

Comment: You can set region in GRASS to limit the operations to a smaller rectangular part of your map. See g.region command or Settings/Computational region from the GRASS GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have started with gdal, why no do the whole process using gdal utilities. I don't see the need for GRASS here (unless you need something more than what you have asked).

I would not create a new raster for all of Europe, rather use the Virtual Raster capability [buildvrt](https://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html), then the gdallocationinfo [locationinfo](https://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html) should get you the elevation at each X-Y locations. i.e.:
(after downloading and unzipping the tiles as you described)

```
gdalbuildvrt srtm.vft srtm*.tif
gdallocationinfo srtm.vft <your x coord> <your y coord>
```

That should do it. You could, of course, write a loop to extract Z values for a list of coord locations.

Comment: I know this is not the style of SE, but still: a "follow"-up question is https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317213/gdal-gdallocationinfo-of-cgiar-mosaic-elevation-data

Comment: It appears the CGIAR files had some issues, so I was basically getting `nodata` values as elevations all over the place. When trying things like https://www.eorc.jaxa.jp/ALOS/en/aw3d30/data/index.htm, the solution proposed here saves space. If one insists on having the explicit `xyz`-file, then `gdal_translate` is the way to go