# GDAL: gdallocationinfo of CGIAR mosaic elevation data

Tags: gdal, dem

I have downloaded tiles from [image: http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/]

http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/ and unpacked the `*.zip` files into a directory. Then I ran, as has been suggested here: [CGIAR SRTM to xyz using GRASS GIS, with sampling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317101/cgiar-srtm-to-xyz-using-grass-gis-with-sampling/317126#317126), the commands

```
#create mosaik (optionally reproject on the fly with -t_srs)
gdalwarp *.tif mosaik.tif
gdalbuildvrt srtm.vft mosaic.tif
```

After this, I can see the following:

```
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: srtm.vft
       mosaic.tif
Size is 48001, 24001
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-10.000416206603404,55.000417150924136)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333333333,-0.000833333333333)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -10.0004162,  55.0004172) ( 10d 0' 1.50"W, 55d 0' 1.50"N)
Lower Left  ( -10.0004162,  34.9995838) ( 10d 0' 1.50"W, 34d59'58.50"N)
Upper Right (  30.0004171,  55.0004172) ( 30d 0' 1.50"E, 55d 0' 1.50"N)
Lower Right (  30.0004171,  34.9995838) ( 30d 0' 1.50"E, 34d59'58.50"N)
Center      (  10.0000005,  45.0000005) ( 10d 0' 0.00"E, 45d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
```

when running `gdalinfo srtm.vft`.
Now, when I try to "query" the data, such as e.g.
`gdallocationinfo srtm.vft <your x coord> <your y coord>`,
with "appropriate" coordinates `x` and `y`, I get stuff like

```
Report:
  Location: (0P,18000L)
  Band 1:
    <LocationInfo><File>mosaic.tif</File></LocationInfo>
    Value: -32768
```

I tried different switches for `gdallocationinfo`, such as `-wgs84` etc.,
to no avail.

My goal, as described in the related SE-question above, is to
have a file with `x,y,z`, where `x,y` is a "locus" in the selected area,
and `z` is the elevation of that locus. I also would like to sample the data
such that any two pairs of coordinates specify locations that are "sufficiently" apart (say, `300-500 km`).

The question, therefore, is:
How exactly to query the above data (using `gdallocationinfo` or otherwise) to achieve my goal?

EDIT: I tried a different tool, `gdal_translate`: `gdal_translate -of XYZ mosaik.tif geotiffas.xyz`, after running `gdalwarp *.tif mosaik.tif`.
But `goetiffas.xyz` contains `nodata` values only, i.e. `-32768`, as the `z`-coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it might work using only two gdal utilities:

Two initial comments.

1. In my earlier suggestion (in the link above) I did **not** suggest to create a mosaic. You can avoid taking up that disk space by just using a vrt.
2. I skipped one crucial parameter to the gdallocationinfo command: `-geoloc`. This tells gdal that the X and Y are in the data coordinate system (not row column numbers)

So I have a directory of several srtm (3 arcsec) data tiles, with names like n29_e034_3arc_v2.tif. Here are the commands and the output:

```
micha@sid-work:SRTM-3arc_v3$ gdalbuildvrt srtm.vrt n*.tif
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
micha@sid-work:SRTM-3arc_v3$ gdalinfo srtm.vrt 
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: srtm.vrt
       n28_e032_3arc_v2.tif
       .... (many more rows) ....
       n33_e035_3arc_v2.tif
       n33_e036_3arc_v2.tif
Size is 6001, 7201
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (31.999583333333334,34.000416666666666)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333333333,-0.000833333333333)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  31.9995833,  34.0004167) ( 31d59'58.50"E, 34d 0' 1.50"N)
Lower Left  (  31.9995833,  27.9995833) ( 31d59'58.50"E, 27d59'58.50"N)
Upper Right (  37.0004167,  34.0004167) ( 37d 0' 1.50"E, 34d 0' 1.50"N)
Lower Right (  37.0004167,  27.9995833) ( 37d 0' 1.50"E, 27d59'58.50"N)
Center      (  34.5000000,  31.0000000) ( 34d30' 0.00"E, 31d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32767
```

The vrt covers from 32 deg (west side) to 37 deg, and 28 (south edge) to 34. Since you are interested in elevations at 500 km intervals, which is about 1/2 degree, you need to extract pixel values at 1/2 degree steps. Here's a loop (in a bash shell in linux) that can do that. Make sure to add the `-geoloc` option:

```
for x in 33 33.5 34 34.5 35 35.5; do for y in 28 28.5 29 29.5 30; do gdallocationinfo -geoloc srtm.vrt $x $y; done; done
.... (many more rows of output) ...
Report:
  Location: (4200P,6000L)
  Band 1:
    <LocationInfo><File>n28_e035_3arc_v2.tif</File><File>n29_e035_3arc_v2.tif</File></LocationInfo>
    Value: 1109
Report:
  Location: (4200P,5400L)
  Band 1:
    <LocationInfo><File>n29_e035_3arc_v2.tif</File></LocationInfo>
    Value: 1037
Report:
  Location: (4200P,4800L)
  Band 1:
    <LocationInfo><File>n29_e035_3arc_v2.tif</File><File>n30_e035_3arc_v2.tif</File></LocationInfo>
    Value: 1578
```

HTH

Comment: Fantastic, I'll give this a try now. Importantly, this avoids projecting the data to Cartesian coordinates.